# Prove that if we redefine the key space, we can assume Gen chooses a key uniformly

Tags: encryption, keys, randomness

I am working on problem 2.1 in Introduction to Modern Cryptography 2nd edition by Katz and Lindell.

> 2.1) Prove that by redefining the key space, we may assume that the key generation algorithm $\textsf{Gen}$ chooses a key uniformly at random from the key space without changing $\Pr[C=c\mid M=m]$ for any $m,c$

We are told to define the key space to be the set of all possible random tapes for the generalized algorithm $\textsf{Gen}$.

I don't understand how we are supposed to prove that this algorithm $\textsf{Gen}$ chooses a key uniformly without knowing the algorithm itself. I am not really sure where to even start with this as I am new to proofs and crypto in general, and and all help will be useful!

What I do know:

$\textsf{Gen}$ is a probabilistic algorithm that outputs some key $k$ chosen according to some distribution. The finite key space $\kappa$ is the set of all possible keys that can be output by $\textsf{Gen}$

Comment: If you are "new to proofs", I suggest you also look into some sort of "intro. to higher mathematics" books to learn about writing and understanding proofs. Crypto proofs can get obtuse very quickly.

Comment: I am doing that currently as well, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: fkraiem, is there any way you could shed some light on this question for me?

Comment: Hint: The fact that you don't know how Gen works means that you should be looking at what you *do* know about Gen. What do you know about it?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know that Gen is a probabilistic algorithm that outputs some key k chosen according to some distribution. The (finite) key space, is the set of all possible output keys that can be output by Gen.

Comment: It may be worth adding the hint of the book to the question

Comment: after a review, i thougth of writing an answer, however the relevant info is a combination of the two answers below and the hint in katz/lindell. the second answer addresses correctly the conceptual modification needed (i.e. redifining the key space), the first answer telling you a flavour of how to modify the algorithm Gen involved. I think that also Enc and Dec needs to be modified. But putting all together is a good exercise at the same time so...

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the late answer, I got busy...

So, you know that $\mathsf{Gen}$ is a probabilistic algorithm. What's a probabilistic algorithm? It's an algorithm which, during its execution, can make some random choices, which can be modeled as coin tosses. In programming terms, the algorithm can use a special coin-tossing function, which returns $0$ or $1$ each with probability $1/2$. The *random tape* is where the machine will write down the result of its coin tosses (or equivalently, where an external coin-tossing device will write the result of the tosses for the machine to read them). Because the results of the coin tosses are uniformy distributed, the contents of the random tape will be uniformly distributed as well and you can use that as your key.

Consider for example a cryptosystem with $\mathcal{K} = \{0,1\}$, and $\mathsf{Gen}$ as follows (in Python-like pseudocode):

```
def Gen():
    coin1 = toss_a_coin()
    coin2 = toss_a_coin()
    if coin1 == 0:
        return 0
    elif coin2 == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

It is clear that the key is not chosen uniformly: $0$ is chosen with probability $3/4$. Now, consider a cryptosystem with $\mathcal{K}' = \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ and $\mathsf{Gen}'$ as follows:

```
def Gen'():
    coin1 = toss_a_coin()
    coin2 = toss_a_coin()
    return (coin1, coin2)
```

Now the key is chosen uniformly. Define encryption and decryption with the keys $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ to be the same as with the key $0$ in the previous system (whatever that is), and encryption/decryption with the key $(1,1)$ to be the same as with the key $1$. It is clear that you get essentially the same cryptosystem, but with the key chosen uniformly.

Comment: This works only when the original algorithm Gen generates keys 0 and 1 with **rational** probabilities. What if $Gen$ generates key 0 with probability 1/e, and key 1 with probability 1 - 1/e, how can you then construct Gen` with equally probable keys?

Answer (score 2):

Consider what it means for a key $k$ to be chosen according to some distribution over key space $\kappa$:

- Assume that $\mathsf{Gen}$ picks key $k$ from key space $\kappa$ with probability $p$.
- Since $\mathsf{Gen}$ is randomized, this means that a $p$-fraction of all the random tapes will lead it to generate $k$ as the key.
- If we now conceptually redefine the key space to be the set of all the *random tapes* $\mathcal{R}$, then the probability of creating the particular *value* $k$ (which should no longer be consider a *key*) is still $p$. This is because the number of tapes that leads $\mathsf{Gen}$ to generate $k$ is still a $p$-fraction of *all* random tapes.
- Then, because the probability $\Pr[C = c | M = m]$ is solely determined by the distribution of the *values* $k$, we see that this conceptual change of key space does not change the value of $\Pr[C = c | M = m]$.
- However, the selection of keys (which are no longer the values $k$) is now *uniformly* distributed over the new key space $\mathcal{R}$.